# What is the limit of CPU and real memory usage for android applications?

Tags: android, memory, limit, cpu

What is the limit of CPU and real memory usage for android applications?

I would like to know it for iPhone, mac and windows as well. Can anybody help me on this regard?
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2):

It's not that simple.

Some phones have more memory than others. Some have faster CPU's. This is true for all of the systems you cite.

As a vague rule, applicable as I write this in early 2012, a phone application should use some number of megabytes measured with 5 digits.  A Mac or Windows application can generally run into 6 digits, and on increasing numbers of systems: low single-digit gigabyte sizes.

The space used by libraries will need to be considered as well.

Now, most of the time, all of those devices will allow you to use roughly 100% of the CPU time, and it's a soft limit. If they need to run something else they just switch away from your task briefly but you still get 95-99% or so.

Of course, if two programs are running, you each get 50%.

Comment: Any other ideas? there are no theoretical values for cpu and real memory usage?